# How can I detect errors programatically when building an egg with setuptools?

Tags: python, error-handling, compiler-errors, setuptools

If I have a script that builds eggs, basically by running

```
python setup.py bdist_egg --exclude-source-files
```

for a number of setup.py files that use `setuptools` to define how eggs are built, is there an easy way to determine if there were any errors in building the egg?

A situation I had recently, was that there was a syntax error in a module. Setuptools spat out a message onto standard error, but continued to create the egg, omitting to broken module. Because this was part of a batch creating a number of eggs, the error was missed, and the result was useless.

Is there a way to detect errors when building an egg programatically, other than just capturing standard error and parsing that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`distutils` use the `py_compile.compile()` function to compile source files. This function takes a `doraise` argument, that when set to `True` raises an exception on compilation errors (the default is to print the errors to stderr). `distutils` don't call `py_compile.compile()` with `doraise=True`, so compilation is not aborted on compilation errors.

To stop on errors and be able to check the `setup.py` return code (it will be nonzero on errors), you could patch the `py_compile.compile()` function. For example, in your `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup
import py_compile

# Replace py_compile.compile with a function that calls it with doraise=True
orig_py_compile = py_compile.compile

def doraise_py_compile(file, cfile=None, dfile=None, doraise=False):
    orig_py_compile(file, cfile=cfile, dfile=dfile, doraise=True)

py_compile.compile = doraise_py_compile

# Usual setup...
```

Comment: Excellent work there! This seems like the sort of thing you'd expect setuptools/distutils to support directly.

Comment: `distutils.core setup()`raises `SystemExit` currently, so can be caught as a `BaseException`